# How to make revolution slider text selectable?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a a problem with the revolution slider, I want to make the text(layer) I add on the revolution slider to be hoverable/selectable if this are the correct terms. I have a mobile number and I want people to be able to copy it if they want, but unfortunately if they can't select it, it's not possible.

Is it possible? If yes, hope someone can tell me how to do it, I wasn't able to find anywhere on the internet this question.

Comment: Do you really expect people to buy a plugin so they develop extra features for you? SO is a place where you come **with code you wrote** but doesn't work the way you expect it to and ask people to point you in the right direction because you tried *everything you could think of*. Where is your code? Where is your programming and documenting effort? The only person you should ask the question above is the plugin developer.

Comment: Thanks but no thanks, I wasn't expecting anyone to buy this plugin just to help me, I was hoping someone had this same problem before and could help me right away, because I've already went trough the documentation and nothing helped.

Comment: If so, please update your question with links to any relevant documentation you went through regarding the problem, even if it didn't help. Another big step towards helping us help you is to provide a testing environment where we could inspect the relevant code and find a solution. Use jsfiddle. You can add external scripts and styles there to replicate your environment.

Comment: What slider are you using? jQuery or WP? I assume it's 5.1?

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes, it's 5.1 wp, but I don't really know what to post on jsfiddle as I'm just starting out with wordpress and my coding abilities are closer to 0, so most of the things I've been able to do are by googling and finding the answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is for Slider Revolution v6.0.2

[image]

6. Layers are Selectable - Toggle **ON** to make the text selectable.

[image]

Refer "Slider Revolution" support page: https://www.themepunch.com/slider-revolution/module-defaults/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your style.css file

```css
.tp-caption{
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -o-user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Themepunch documentation for this.

https://www.themepunch.com/faq/allow-for-caption-text-highlighting/

I hope this helps!

Comment: @felix-dragoi. I'd be very grateful if you could mark this as the answer if you found if helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Link is not pointing to the answer. Link is redirecting to the main support page.

Comment: @Gvtha thanks for pointing this out. As it's been 2 years I imagine Themepunch have updated their website and not added redirects to new pages :(

Answer (score 0):

In slider revolution, at 'Style' tab click at down arrow as shown in picture:[image]

then you'll see a selectbox with 'bulb' icon, choose **On** from the list to make the text selectable when your slider will be in preview.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I asked the support. Just add this to your Custom CSS of the Slider

```
.tp-caption.tp-layer-selectable{
-webkit-user-select: text !important; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
-moz-user-select: text !important; /* Firefox 2+ */
-ms-user-select: text !important; /* IE 10+ */
user-select: text !important; /* Standard syntax */
}
```